# Postgres SQL : how do I recalculate average value, after an existing value from the average has been changed

Tags: sql, postgresql, math, average, mathematical-optimization

Using the function below, when you first rate a title, and then afterwards give a different rating for the title the averagerating for that title will be incorrect.

The number of votes for title 'tt9910206' is 4, and averagerating is 8 before the function is called.
When calling the function the first time, and giving a rating of 7, the numvotes is 5 and the expected average is 7,8, which the function does return. But when changing the rating from 7 to 8 the expected result is 8, yet the function returns 7,84.

I suspect it's because the function doesnt take into account that the user has undone their rating, when recalculating the average.
How do I fix this, so when a user changes their rating, the function recalculates the average by using the averagerating number from before a user gave it a rating in the first place?

Edit: Found the answer here

[Finding an average after replacing a current value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56843475/finding-an-average-after-replacing-a-current-value)

Answer (score 0):

You may have other issues in your function.  But you seem to be forgetting that Postgres does integer division.  So, `1/2` is `0`, not `0.5`.

I notice calculations like this:

```
count( user_titlerate.tconst ) / count( user_titlerate.tconst )
```

`COUNT()` returns and integer.  I usually modify this to:

```
count( user_titlerate.tconst ) * 1.0 / count( user_titlerate.tconst )
```

But you can use other constructs such as:

```
count( user_titlerate.tconst )::numeric / count( user_titlerate.tconst )
```

Comment: oh that part is just to add +1 to the numvotes, basically everytime a user makes a new rating, the amount of rates a movie has goes up by 1. its supposed to be an int I have simplified this part here                                                                                                           
        ( title_basicsnew.numvotes +1) this does the exact same as the code above.